# Image or JS not showing on Magento 2

Tags: magento2, javascript, css, htaccess

I've just installed Magento 2 onto my production server under a development subdomain. The install appeared to have been successful but I've noticed there are no images or working javascript in both the frontend and the backend.

After inspecting the source code, I found that files being called in such as http://dev.website.com/pub/static/frontend/Magento/luma/en_GB/css/print.css don't actually exist. Any thoughts? I tried solutions on several stacks but haven't had any luck.

Comment: run the setup upgrade and static content deploy comment

Answer (score 1):

As Jeeva Chezhiyan suggests you can run

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

however if this is development site, you may want to switch to developer mode and have the static contents be updated as you develop the site.
To do that, you need to run:

```
php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer
```

With this mode, you should not need to run the deploy command from above

Comment: You beat me to the answer ;) as an additional precaution, ensure that the permissions are set correctly for var and pub folders